# Intuition on the sum of first (n-1) numbers is equal to the number of ways of picking 2 items out of n.

Tags: intuition

While going through an equation today i realized that sum of first (n-1) numbers is [n*(n-1)/2] which is equal to combinations of two items out of n i.e [n!/((n-2)! * 2!)]. I need some intuition on how these two things are related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wolfram proof without words](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ProofWithoutWords12N1NChoose2/). Note that this uses Pascal's Triangle.

Comment: I don't think that the math helps at all here.  That just gives a proof that they're equal, rather than providing an intuition for why they're equal.

Comment: Yes the math does not help here as your proof is something on which the question is based. The question is "Why are these two completely different equations related?"

Comment: This answer is perfectly fine! The number of dots is the arithmetic sum of the rows: `(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+...+2+1`.

Comment: @Shashank, I think the linked "proof without words" gives good intuition.

Comment: Sorry guys, the link to wolfram gives a good intuition but the explanation above is a bit misleading, so i have removed it and selected this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

You're asking why the number of ways to pick 2 cards out of a deck of `n` is the same as the sum 1 + 2 + ... + (n-1).

The reason is that there are (n-1) ways to pair the first card with another card, plus (n-2) ways to pair the second card with one of the remaining cards, plus (n-3) ways to pair the third card...

Answer (score 4):

One way to think of this is to map it to an intermediary representation - namely, a triangle made of boxes:

```
 *****
 ****
 ***
 **
 *
```

Let's suppose that this triangle has width and height $n$. The number of dots in this triangle is equal to $1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

We can interpret this triangle as every way of choosing two elements out of $n + 1$ by expanding it out into a 0/1 matrix:

```
    | 1   2  ... n-1  n
----+------------------
n+1 | 1   1   1   1   1
n   | 1   1   1   1   0
n-1 | 1   1   1   0   0
... | 1   1   0   0   0
2   | 1   0   0   0   0
1   | 0   0   0   0   0
```

If we take all unordered pairs of two numbers, then we can always sort the pair by putting the bigger number first.  Each possible way to do this corresponds to a 1 entry in this matrix.  For example, the pairing $(n+1, n)$ corresponds to the upper-right corner, since $n+1 > n$.  Similarly, $(n+1, 1)$ corresponds to the top-left corner.  If you count up the number of 1s in this matrix, you'll note that it's half the area of the matrix.  There are $n + 1$ rows and $n$ columns, so the area is $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$.

We can also arrive here by noting that there are $n$ 1s in the first row, then $n - 1$, then $n - 2$, ..., then 1.  Thus $1 + 2 + ... + n$ is equal to the number of unordered pairs drawn from $n + 1$ numbers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: if width and height are n then the triangle should have `n*n/2` not `(n*n-1)/2`

Comment: @zerocool Thanks for pointing that out. I had meant to discuss the number of dots that make up the discrete triangle I had drawn out, rather than the area of a geometric triangle of width and height $n$. I've updated the answer to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's count 2-subsets from a set of size $n$.

Certainly this is $n\choose2$.

Alternatively, we can count by cases.  First some details:

Let $N$ be the set $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots x_{n}\}$ where $x_i < x_{i+1}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n - 1$.

We seek to count how many unique subsets $\{a, b\} \subseteq N$ there exist where $a < b$.

Cases:

1) $b = x_n$ $\hspace{14mm}$  As $a < b$, there remain $(n - 1)$ choices for a.

2) $b = x_{n-1}$ $\hspace{9mm}$  There remain $(n - 2)$ choices for $a$.

3) $b = x_{n-2}$ $\hspace{9mm}$  There remain $(n - 3)$ choices for $a$.

$\hspace{10mm}\vdots$

$n$) $b = x_0$ $\hspace{13mm}$  There remain $0$ choices for $a$.

Summing over each of these distinct cases gives us $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i$.

Hence, $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} =$ $n\choose2$ $= 1 + 2 + \ldots (n-1)$.